How can I balance Performance and Consistency in AWS Lambda
I'm developing an AWS Lambda function that processes data from an SQS queue. The function needs to maintain a consistent state for accurate calculations. I'm exploring two options:

Sequential processing: Using reserved concurrency to ensure only one instance runs at a time, performing calculations within the function, and storing results in ElastiCache.
In-memory caching: Utilizing ElastiCache for intermediate calculations to improve performance, but concerned about potential data inconsistencies due to concurrent access.
I'm seeking advice on the best approach to guarantee data integrity and consistency in this scenario.

I'm in the initial stages of designing a Lambda function that requires state management. I'm exploring different architectural patterns to ensure data consistency and avoid potential issues.

why is it lambda?

You can connect the Lambda function to a FIFO SQS Queue. This will ensure that messages with the same MessageGroupId are always passed-in order and new messages from that Group will not be passed to a Lambda function while earlier messages are 'in-flight'. This is preferable to a Reserved Concurrency because it means that multiple Lambda functions can run, with each handling messages from different MessageGroupIds.
